# IPython notebook on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, ipython

Have someone made the experience of deploying an IPython notebook on Heroku. I don't find any information about this.

Can someone please explain me how to set up such an notebook on Heroku?
Thanks. :)

Comment: Two things are required for the IPython Notebook: WebSockets and ZeroMQ/PyZMQ.  Are these both available on Heroku?

Comment: I tried to install ZeroMQ/PyZMQ and it wasn't possible, so I think I'm out of luck with Heroku.

Comment: I guess that's how it goes.  The Notebook works great on EC2, and is trivial to get running with [starcluster](http://web.mit.edu/star/cluster/).

Comment: I'm sure you can install Python dependencies from PyPi on Heroku. Since 20th of august `pyzmq` compiles and installs ZeroMQ if it is not already installed on the system. Previously you would probably have had to install `pyzmq-static`. Read more here http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq-static/2.2 and here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq/2.2.0.1

Comment: Any update on this guys?

Answer (score 1):

See http://nbviewer.ipython.org/, it's hosted on heroku :

```
$ host nbviewer.ipython.org
nbviewer.ipython.org is an alias for nbviewer.herokuapp.com.
nbviewer.herokuapp.com has address 107.22.226.64
```

You can even access your own notebooks there. See for example this NumPy tutorial : http://nbviewer.ipython.org/2847673/

And of course, the very cool XKCD plotting library : http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/jakevdp.github.com/downloads/notebooks/XKCD_plots.ipynb

Comment: Note that nbviewer does static views of the notebooks, not the full interactive, editable experience.